# jq: treat single object as 1-element array

Tags: json, jq

I have several .json files (or rather, .xml files pre-parsed by [xq/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)) that I want to parse. Unfortunately, the element I want to read (`.size`) can be inside an extra array (in which case I'd `select` one of them) or just a single object, as follows:

```
{
  "Obj1": {
    "size": "123"
  },
  "Obj2": [
    { "size": "3" },
    { "size": "5" }
  ]
}
```

In case of `Obj1`, the query `jq '.[].size'` yields "123", as expected, but it fails for `Obj2` with the error *Cannot index array with string 'size'*.
In case of `Obj2`, to get a single `size` value (e.g. the maximum one), the query `jq '.[]|max.size` yields "5", as expected. But this fails for `Obj1` with the error *object `{"size":"123"}` cannot be iterated over*.

**Is there an expression that treats the single sub-object `{"size":"123"}` like an array with one element, or otherwise allow me to treat both cases with the same query?**

Comment: @peak: Actually, no. For this simple case, `max.size` does the right thing. Since there is only one key-value pair (with key `size`) in the object, both `max_by(.size)|.size` and `max()` both yield `5`, regardless of comparing just the value of `.size` or the whole object `{"size":"5"}`.

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood your question. It would perhaps help if you followed the `mcve` guidelines more closely.  In any case, please see the updated answer.

Comment: I've read the question and your comment thrice and still have no idea what you're asking here.

Answer (score 4):

A terse solution to this problem is provided by the alternative operator `//` and the optional operator `?`:

```
jq .[] | (max? // .) | .size
```

- If the result of `.[]` is an array, `max` returns the maximum element of the array.
- Othewise, the result of `.[]` is not an array, `max` will fail, the `?` operator will suppress the error, and the `//` operator will return the `.` instead.
  In both cases, a single sub-object containing a `size` key is returned.

Comment: Great solution, worked for me (in a different context)

Comment: From this I figured out `[.[]? // .]` to ensure a single element is treated as an array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would probably be to check whether or not the input is an object.  Assuming the input must either be an object or an array of objects, you could do worse than:

```
if type == "object" then .size else map(.size)|max end
```

In your case, I gather you would want to precede this by `.[]`:

```
.[] | if type == "object" then .size else map(.size)|max end
```

This produces:

```
"123"
"5"
```

Of course, if you want the numeric max, you would have to make suitable modifications.